# Laravel shared hosting - Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater

Tags: php, shared-hosting, laravel

I made a website with laravel for one of my clients, and they are using a shared hosting.

And i installed laravel to its home folder, so `public` folder became the `public_html` folder in host, and i changed it to `public_html` in the paths.php file.

And, after i installed it, i started to get

> Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater

error. And after i googled it, everybody says that i need to comment out safe_mode from my `php.ini` file, but since i am on a shared hosting, there is no way for me to change that.

Any suggestions?

P.S: My client does not have a technical knowledge, and after they paid the money to hosting, they don't want to change it, and want me to handle this situation.

Comment: @Khuram excuse me but, i couldn't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely due to your error reporting level.  Try ignoring `E_DEPRECATED` and possibly `E_WARNING`.

If you are running Laravel 3, you should be able to set your ignored error levels in application/config/error.php around line 16.

```php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Ignored Error Levels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you simply specify the error levels that should be ignored by the
| Laravel error handler. These levels will still be logged; however, no
| information about them will be displayed.
|
*/

'ignore' => array(E_WARNING, E_NOTICE, E_USER_NOTICE, E_DEPRECATED, E_USER_DEPRECATED),
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini file and find the safe_mode declaration and comment it out. You might have to restart Apache after that.