# Magento cronjob error

Tags: magento, cron

I'm trying to set up a cronjob for magento.
My cronjob is:

```
*/5 * * * *  /bin/sh /var/www/vhosts/#######/httpdocs/cron.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This works well, but cron.sh is giving this error:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imap.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
[eAccelerator] This build of "eAccelerator" was compiled for PHP version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9. Rebuild it for your PHP version (5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14) or download precompiled binaries.
PHP Warning:  Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  realpath(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 0 is not allowed to access /var/www/vhosts/########/httpdocs/app owned by uid 10001 in /var/www/vhosts/########/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 273
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message ' is not a directory or not readable by this user' in /var/www/vhosts/########/httpdocs/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/########/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(278): Mage::throwException(' is not a direc...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/########/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(752): Mage::setRoot()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/########/httpdocs/cron.php(29): Mage::isInstalled()
#3 {main}
 thrown in /var/www/vhosts/########/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 594
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted the first line of /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcript.ini (Number 12)

```
This may help you

For reference :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/573436
```

eaccelerator : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EAccelerator

safe_mode : just comment safe_mode or [Laravel shared hosting - Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959918/laravel-shared-hosting-directive-safe-mode-is-deprecated-in-php-5-3-and-grea)

app :file permission issue give -R 777

Comment: I replaced the #'s for ;. The warnings are gone. Still have the other issues.

Comment: please specify issue, will try to suggest

Comment: everything, except the "PHP Deprecated" warnings

Comment: Strange; i already had give cron.sh and cron.php the right permissions. But when i commented save mode out, everything works.

thnx!